# Уменьшение масштаба при переходе не 3ий bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Так как поставили требование верстать под IE9 и с помощью bootstrap, приходится переходить на третью версию, т.к. она поддерживается IE9, я заменил файл со стилями, в итоге уменьшился масштаб страницы по какой-то причине.

Скриншот верстки с bootstrap3:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот верстки с bootstrap4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro', sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro';
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro-Bold.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Bold.svg#GothamPro-Bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro';
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/GothamPro.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/GothamPro.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro.svg#GothamPro') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro';
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro-Medium.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Medium.svg#GothamPro-Medium') format('svg');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro';
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro-Light.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/GothamPro-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Light.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Light.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/GothamPro-Light.svg#GothamPro-Light') format('svg');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}

.header__header-top {
  background-color: #0c0f17;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.header__navigation {
  vertical-align: sub;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__navigation-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1.8rem;
}

.header__navigation-link {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #aeaeae;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.header__navigation-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header__navigation-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header__icon-box {
  vertical-align: sub;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__icon-social {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aeaeae;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header__icon-social:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__header-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <nav class="header__navigation">
            <ul class="header__navigation-menu">
              <li class="header__navigation-item">
                <a href="#" class="header__navigation-link">
         Главная
        </a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation-item">
                <a href="#" class="header__navigation-link">
         Каталог
        </a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation-item">
                <a href="#" class="header__navigation-link">
         Акции и новости
        </a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation-item">
                <a href="#" class="header__navigation-link">
         Контакты
        </a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation-item">
                <a href="#" class="header__navigation-link">
         Оплата и доставка
        </a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation-item">
                <a href="#" class="header__navigation-link">
         Оптовый клиент
        </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <div class="header__icon-box">
            <a href="#" class="header__icon-social">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="header__icon-social">
              <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="header__icon-social">
              <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="header__icon-social">
              <i class="fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="header__icon-social">
              <i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <form method="GET" class="header__search-place">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск" class="header__search-field">
            <button class="header__search-button">
       
      </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__contacts">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <a href="index.html" class="logo-box">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logotype" class="logo-box__logotype">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 offset-lg-1">
          <div class="header__contact-box">
            <div class="header__contact-icon-box">

            </div>
            <div class="header__contact-info">
              <h5 class="header__contact-name">
                Наш адрес
              </h5>
              <span class="header__contact-adress">
        г.Красноярск Красноярский <br /> рабочий 160/7
       </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

На всякий случай ссылка на песочницу: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdWWgE

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, нет, такого нет

Comment: Из списка миграции "Global font-size increased from 14px to 16px."
У вас вижу размеры заданы шрифтов в rem, думаю в этом проблема.

Comment: @Nilsan точно... а я не обратил на это внимание

Comment: @Nilsan, пишите ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из списка миграции "Global font-size increased from 14px to 16px." У вас вижу размеры заданы шрифтов в rem, думаю в этом проблема.